# Como especificar um endereço que está fora de um conjunto de 'div'

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Fiz um menu com efeito 'hover' porém pretendo mudar a cor da barra cinza do menu, ao encostar o cursor nos botões "pesquisar e News" mas não sei como especificar o endereço .navbar(responsável pela cor cinza da barra do menu) aplicando o efeito 'hover' nele, até porque ele está como principal acima das outras divs, existe algum modo de fazer a barra cinza mudar de cor ao encostar o cursor nos itens 'pesquisar' e 'News' ??

```css
body{background-color:#09C;}
.navbar{ overflow:hidden; 
background-color:#666; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navbar a{float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none; 
}
.navbar a:hover, .menu:hover .bt{background-color: #0C0;
}

.menu{float: left;
overflow: hidden; 
}
.menu .bt{font-size: 16px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #FFF;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin:0;
}
.menu:hover .sub{ display:block;
}
.sub{display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color:#f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
}
.sub a{float: none;
color: #000;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#">Pesquisas</a>
<div class="menu">
<button class="bt">News</button>
  <div class="sub">
   <a href="#">Links</a>
   <a href="#">Links</a>
   <a href="#">Links</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse foi un jeito que encontrei para corrigir isso só com CSS

Cara usando uma combinação de pseudo-elementos `::after` com as cores que vc precisa, em vez de usar o `background-color` direto no elemento html principal vc consegue.

Repare que nem encostei no seu HTML, fiz tudo no CSS nos `::after` e `:hover::after`

Mas precisei mexer em alguns estilos da Navbar.... Ela estava com `overflow:hidden`, e depois que coloquei o `position:relativer` precisei tirar esse overflow. Para corrigir eu coloquei um valor de `height` fixo.

```css
    body{background-color:#09C;}
.navbar{ 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: relative;
height: 46px;
}
.navbar a{float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none; 
}
.navbar a:hover, .menu:hover .bt{background-color: #0C0;
}

/* estilos das cores*/
.navbar::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #666;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -10;
    }
    .navbar a::after , .navbar .menu::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .navbar a:hover::after {
      background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    .navbar .menu:hover::after {
      background-color: #0000ff;
    }


.menu{float: left;
overflow: hidden; 
}
.menu .bt{font-size: 16px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #FFF;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin:0;
}
.menu:hover .sub{ display:block;
}
.sub{display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color:#f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
}
.sub a{float: none;
color: #000;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Pesquisas</a>
    <div class="menu">
      <button class="bt">News</button>
      <div class="sub">
        <a href="#">Links</a>
        <a href="#">Links</a>
        <a href="#">Links</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```